# Add class to menu link href tag?

Tags: routes, navigation

I know that using hook_menu_link I can add classes to the `<li>` tags but I need to add a class to the `<a>` tags within the `<li>` of a menu. I've looked and can't find a way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from `hook_menu_link`. You want to access the `$vars['element']['#localized_options']['attributes']['class']`

Something like this

```
$element = $vars['element'];
$element['#localized_options']['attributes']['class'][] = 'your-class';
$output = l($link_text, $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
```

Then return the $output in the `<li>`. Be sure to account for `$vars['element']['#below']` if you have a sub-menu.

Comment: Thank you, forgot to post that I found the same solution.

Comment: Just a correction. It's a theme_menu_link not hook_menu_link.