# Implement hook_menu_block_tree_alter() to change CSS classes

Tags: 7, hooks

I have installed the [Menu block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block) module. I am very happy with the result, but I'd like to change some classes in the structure.

This is what I get right now.

```html
<div class="content">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="first last expanded">
      <a class="active" href="http://example.com">News</a>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li class="first last leaf">
          <a class="active" href="http://example.com">Test</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is what I want.

```html
<div class="content">
  <ul id="nav-list">
    <li class="first last expanded has-submenu">
      <a class="active" href="http://example.com">News</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="first last leaf">
          <a class="active" href="http://example.com">Test</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Basically, I  want to:

1. Change the `<ul>`'s classes and attributes (This is level specific, so it's not the same for the primary/secondary `<ul>`.)
2. Add the *has-submenu* class to an `<li>` if it contains another submenu

As explained in [Menu Block's documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1934824), I implemented `hook_menu_block_tree_alter()` in the *template.php* file.

```php
function THEME_menu_block_tree_alter(&$tree, &$config) {
  foreach ($tree as $key => &$value) {
    if ($tree[$key]['link']['access'] && !$tree[$key]['link']['hidden']) {
      $items[] = $tree[$key];
    }
  }
    
  $num_items = count($items);

  foreach ($items as $i => &$data) {
    $class = array();
   
    if ($data['link']['has_children']) {
      $class[] = 'has-submenu';
    }
    $element['#attributes']['class'] = $class;
  }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I don't really have deep understanding of how and where to implement this hook function. Also my impression is that more detailed documentation is missing for this specific hook.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Just to be sure, did you change `THEME` with the short name of the theme? If THEME is not the short name of the theme, that hook will never get invoked.

Comment: Hi @kiamlaluno :-) Yes I did so, but it wouldn't even do anything if adding a `var_dump($example)` or `drupal_set_message("Example")`.. I decided to go the way @sareed explained in his answer below, but still..shouldn't this be working? And is template.php the place to put it or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Other than the regular clear cache I am not sure why that would not be called. I do not have much experience with that hook. However I am fairly certain [`theme_menu_link`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7) would work here as well. Take a look at the answer [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/142391/add-class-to-menu-link-href-tag/142418#142418). A test for `$vars['element']['#below']` should allow you to accomplish what you want.

**Note:** If you have a small menu you can always add classes to menu items through the UI.

**EDIT:** To answer part 1 try something like this (taken from bootstrap_menu_link):

```
if ($element['#below']) {
  if ((!empty($element['#original_link']['depth'])) && ($element['#original_link']['depth'] == 1)) {
    // Add our own wrapper.
    unset($element['#below']['#theme_wrappers']);
    $sub_menu = '<ul class="dropdown-menu">' . drupal_render($element['#below']) . '</ul>';
    // Generate as standard dropdown.
    $element['#title'] .= ' <span class="caret"></span>';
    $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'dropdown';
    $element['#localized_options']['html'] = TRUE;

    // Set dropdown trigger element to # to prevent inadvertant page loading
    // when a submenu link is clicked.
    $element['#localized_options']['attributes']['data-target'] = '#';
    $element['#localized_options']['attributes']['class'][] = 'dropdown-toggle';
    $element['#localized_options']['attributes']['data-toggle'] = 'dropdown';
  }
}
```

Comment: So I cleared cache, but wouldn't change the fact. Also trying to "drupal_set_message()" something or var_dump($tree)" will not work. I must be doing something wrong.. Could you give me some more help on how to do it using "theme_menu_link"? Thx anymway

Comment: You add the function to your template.php `function YOUR_THEME_menu_link($vars) {}`. I edited the answer to add the link (my bad I missed that first go around). The documentation should help a lot just pay attention to how the return string is set up. If it is wrong your menu can go away and cause other issues.

Comment: Thanks for the help! will look at this. I will leave this question open for a moment though, as this only covers one part of my question.

Comment: Sounds good, what parts are do you need clarification on. Perhaps add edits to your question to track progress.

Comment: So I managed to add classes to the `<li>` parts using `theme_menu_link()` (what is point 2 in my question).
Concerning point 1 in my question, I cant figure out how to add/change/remove the <ul>'s class and id attributes (level specific, so not the same for the primary/secondary <ul>).

Answer (score 0):

`HOOK_menu_block_tree_alter(&$tree, &$config)` is not a theme hook. You have to use it in a custom module and then it will work. So if you create a module called "mymodule, then put the following code in the `myModule.module` file, it should print the arguments:

```
/**
 * Alter the menu tree and its configuration before the tree is rendered.
 *
 * @param $tree
 *   An array containing the unrendered menu tree.
 * @param $config
 *   An array containing the configuration of the tree.
 */
function mymodule_menu_block_tree_alter(&$tree, &$config) {
  dsm($config);
  dsm($tree);
}
```

I'm not really sure if you can qualify it further with the menu block name--it didn't work when I tried that. You might have to just conditionally select the menu block you want on that page, if there's more than one.

Comment: If the hook is invoked using `drupal_alter()`, also a theme can implement it, since it is an alter hook. Differently from the other hooks, alter hooks can be implemented from themes too, in Drupal 7 and if the module uses `drupal_alter()` to invoke the hook. Differently, they could not be invoked.

Answer (score 0):

In the 7.x-2.x branch, that hook is invoked using the following code. (See [menu_block.module](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/menu_block/tree/menu_block.module?h=7.x-2.x).)

```
  // Allow alteration of the tree and config before we begin operations on it.
  drupal_alter('menu_block_tree', $tree, $config);

  // Localize the tree.
  if (module_exists('i18n_menu')) {
    $tree = i18n_menu_localize_tree($tree);
  }
```

Since [`drupal_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/drupal_alter/7.x) contains the following code, even a theme can implement that alter hook.

```
// Allow the theme to alter variables after the theme system has been
// initialized.
global $theme, $base_theme_info;
if (isset($theme)) {
  $theme_keys = array();
  foreach ($base_theme_info as $base) {
    $theme_keys[] = $base->name;
  }
  $theme_keys[] = $theme;
  foreach ($theme_keys as $theme_key) {
    $function = $theme_key . '_' . $hook;
    if (function_exists($function)) {
      $functions[$cid][] = $function;
    }
    if (isset($extra_types)) {
      foreach ($extra_types as $extra_type) {
        $function = $theme_key . '_' . $extra_type . '_alter';
        if (function_exists($function)) {
          $functions[$cid][] = $function;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The theme implementing the hook must be the theme used to render the page, or one of its parent themes. Differently, the alter hook would not be invoked.

The same is true for the 7.x-3.x branch of the module. (See its [menu_block.module](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/menu_block/tree/menu_block.module?h=7.x-3.x).)

If you edited an already enabled theme, or one of its parent themes to add the alter hook, then Drupal will not notice you added a new hook, since it saves in its cache the list of implemented hooks.
For Drupal to notice the new hook, you should visit the page listing all the modules, and install a module that you then uninstall, or disable a module you then re-enable. In this way, Drupal will clear the cache containing the list of the implemented hooks, and it will notice the new hook.

It could also be the alter hook has been implemented for the wrong theme, for example one that is never used for any page, or that is not the parent theme of any theme used for the page shown in your site.